# How to take ints from user using fgets in C?

Tags: c, pointers, fgets

I'm a beginner at C. I'm trying to write a program that computes the volume based on user's input of 3 integers using `fgets()`, and I'm struggling to understand why my code is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int volumn(int a, int b, int c);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* height, width, depth;
    fgets(&height, 10, stdin);
    fgets(&width, 10, stdin);
    fgets(&depth, 10, stdin);

    printf("\nThe volumn is %d\n", volumn(atoi(&height), atoi(&width), atoi(&depth)));

    return 0;
}

int volumn(int a, int b, int c){
    return a * b * c;
}
```

**EDIT**: I'm getting the following errors/warnings when I run the code above:

```
goodbyeworld.c:8:11: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to
      parameter of type 'char *'; remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    fgets(&height, 10, stdin);
          ^~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:238:30: note: 
      passing argument to parameter here
char    *fgets(char * __restrict, int, FILE *);
                                ^
goodbyeworld.c:12:48: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to
      parameter of type 'const char *'; remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    printf("\nThe volumn is %d\n", volumn(atoi(&height), atoi(&width), a...
                                               ^~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:132:23: note: 
      passing argument to parameter here
int      atoi(const char *);
                          ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you be a bit more precise about how it's not working? Is it compiling? Do you get any error messages? If it runs, what happends when it runs? Please edit your question.

Comment: Always, when compiling, enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)  then fix the warnings.  With the posted code you would see two warnings: 1) unused variable 'argc' 2) unused variable 'argv[]' along with the warnings you are already seeing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, a definition like

```
 char* height, width, depth;
```

make `height` a pointer to `char` and the rest two as `char`s.

Secondly (not much relevant *here*, but in general, important), You did not allocate memory to the pointers you want to use (if at all).

If you have a fixed input length decided as `10`, you can simply make all the three variables as array ans use the *names* directly, like

```
#define VAL 10
char height[VAL] = {0};
char width[VAL] = {0};
char depth[VAL] = {0};
```

and then

```
fgets(height, 10, stdin);
```

finally, consider using [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) over `atoi()` for better error handling.

Comment: I'd consider the missing allocation *very* relevant here, too

Comment: @FelixPalmen as OP's passing `&height`, the whole thing is wrong, anyway. :)

Comment: Indeed, but just fixing *that* issue, the segfault is next ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen that's why I switched to arrays. :)

Comment: How do I use strtol() to convert height to an int? I tried atoi(height), and it did not work.

Comment: @tbee: how in the world could a simple `atoi(height)` not work??

Comment: @Jongware I was running atoi(&height). Oops. atoi(height) does work.

Comment: @Jongware,  an atoi() can fail when the string pointed to by the parameter has no leading numeric value(s)  for instance "abcedf" or "   123"

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution of your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int volumn(int a, int b, int c){
    return a*b*c;
}

int main(){

    char height[10];
    char width[10];
    char depth[10];

    printf("Please enter size of object:\n");
    fgets(height, 10, stdin);
    fgets(width, 10, stdin);
    fgets(depth, 10, stdin);

    int valheight = atoi(height);
    int valwidth = atoi(width);
    int valdepth = atoi(depth);

    printf("\nThe volumn is %i\n", volumn(valheight, valwidth, valdepth));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't. Using `atoi` to convert input to integers when you can get the input *as* integers is pointless. What you are looking for is `scanf`.

Your code would look like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int volumn (int a, int b, int c);

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int height;
    int width;
    int depth;

    scanf ("%10d", &height);
    scanf ("%10d", &width);
    scanf ("%10d", &depth);

    printf ("\nThe volumn is %d\n", volumn (height, width, depth));

    return 0;
}

int
volumn (int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a * b * c;
}
```

Comment: I never found `scanf()` of any use for real-world *interactive* input (and I assume that is what OP wants to do here)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I fail to see how `fgets` is anymore "interactive" than `scanf`

Comment: using `fgets()`, you can react on unexpected input properly, something happening quite often in the interactive case.

Comment: Don't both only return once a newline/EOF is encountered? If so, I still don't see how `fgets` is any better. Get the input, and do whatever you want to validate it after. With `scanf` you can at least specify what kind of data you're expecting, making validation much simpler.

Comment: Maybe simpler in some cases, but much less flexible, because it won't give you access to the original input. I'd always go with some other solution, e.g. `strtol()` like suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Just use a `%s` then. Besides, conversions add unnecessary execution time, and converting something like "I'd like it to be 10" with `strtol` wouldn't give you what you'd expect anyway, while the `%d` with `scanf` allows it to fail and prompt again.

Comment: This makes even less sense now. `%s` IS a conversion, of course it takes time, and it's utterly pointless when you want nothing other than that string.

Comment: when calling scanf(), always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.   When using the format specifier '%s', always include a length modifier, so the user cannot overrun the input buffer.

Comment: @FelixPalmen My point is `%s` gives you more or less the same behavior as `fgets`, minus the forced newline. And no, `%s` is not a conversion, it's more of a type check, `scanf` fails if the input doesn't match the specifiers. With `fgets`, you have to get the string, which is one action, and then you have to convert it, which is another action, which may or may not throw an error because the input may or may not be a value convertible to a long.

Comment: @user3629249 I had hoped that the use of `%10s` was implied by my use of `%10d` in my answer.

Comment: For the term *conversion*, see [`scanf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). And no, an operation is not more efficient, just because you use one big library functions with tons of bells and whistles instead of 2 much simpler ones that even give you a lot more control. I rest my case, `scanf()` is a bad idea, *at least* for interactive input.

Comment: @FelixPalmen So your argument is semantics. My point is `fgets` requires at least two actions, one of which is an explicit type conversion which the programmer has to take separate care to check against errors, meaning even more work and more code, more slow and more bloat. While `scanf`, with or without a type conversion (because it doesn't always do a conversion), does all of this simultaneously, simplifying everything, without sacrificing anything. You've failed to show how `fgets` is any better for "interactivity", or generally, better in any other way.

Comment: @FelixPalmen All of this is moot anything, as OP has their answer. They seem fine with an `fgets` and `strtol` mix.

Answer (score 0):

in C, the name of an array degrades to a pointer to the first address of the array,

However, the dimensions are already (only) pointers that point to nothing.

The code needs to actually have them point to allocated memory.

Typically that would be accomplished via code similar to:

```
if( NULL == (height = malloc( 20 ) ) ) { // handle error and exit }
```

I use 20 rather than 10 because a int can be 13 characters plus sign plus newline plus NUL byte and 20 leaves a bit of extra room.

The first parameter to fgets() is a pointer to the input buffer and 'height', etc are defined as pointers so do not need another '&'

However, using malloc() also adds the requirement to pass each of the three pointers to free() before exiting the program.

remembering that a int (on a 32 bit system) can handle +/-2gig I.E. 10 digits+sign+newline+NUL  is a (depending on the OS) 13 or 14 characters.

Suggest, use:

```
int main( void )
{
    int height;
    int width;
    int depth;

    if( 1 != (scanf( "%d", &height ) ) ) 
    { // then scanf failed
        perror( "scanf for height failed: );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    similar statements for the other two inputs

    printf ("\nThe volumn is %d\n", volumn (height, width, depth));
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```